# join multible json files in on json with its path as a key

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I have some json files that I want to join them in one json file, but I need to set everyone under a key of its path so,I can get them very easy when I use the big json file

```
            const jsonFullPath = path.relative(root, file).split(path.sep).join('.')
                .replace(/(_[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?)?\.json/, '') + '.' ;
            const obj = [jsonFullPath];
            let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(file);
            let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

the code above called in an array of json files

anyone can help please

an example is like this :

```
{  "sessionTimer": {
"accessibleTimingOut": "{{timeoutMinutes}} minutes until this 
page times out. Move your mouse pointer or press any key to 
extend the time with {{extendMinutes}} minutes.",
"reload": "Reload",
"timedOut": "The page has timed out and needs to be reloaded.",
"timingOut": "seconds until this page times out and needs to be 
 reloaded. Move your mouse pointer or press any key to extend the 
  time with {{extendMinutes}} minutes."
 },
 "header": {
"screenReaderLabel": "Poslechnout",
"myAccountLabel": "Přihlásit se",
"myAccountLogoutLabel": "Odhlásit se",
"myAccountPagesLabel": "Moje stránky",
"newToTheLibrary": "Jste v knihovně noví?",
"joinTheLibraryLabel": "Registrovat do knihovny",
"openingsLabel": "Provozní doba",
"languageLabel": "Jazyk"
 },
 "branchOpeningHours": {
"headerLabel": "Provozní doba",
"closedLabel": "Zavřeno",
"todayLabel": "Dnes",
"navigationBackLabel": "Zpět",
"navigationNextLabel": "Další",
"navigationPreviousLabel": "Předchozí",
"serviceTypeClosedLabel": "Zavřeno",
"serviceTypeStaffedLabel": "S personálem",
"serviceTypeSelfServiceLabel": "Samoobsluha",
"typeRegularLabel": "Pravidelný",
"typeSpecialLabel": "Zvláštní",
"viewAllLabel": "Zobrazit veškerou otevírací dobu"
 }
}
```

after the join will be some think like this ;

```
"modules.provider.assets.locales.en_US.translation":{  
"sessionTimer": {
"accessibleTimingOut": "{{timeoutMinutes}} minutes until this 
page times out. Move your mouse pointer or press any key to 
extend the time with {{extendMinutes}} minutes.",
"reload": "Reload",
"timedOut": "The page has timed out and needs to be reloaded.",
"timingOut": "seconds until this page times out and needs to be 
 reloaded. Move your mouse pointer or press any key to extend the 
  time with {{extendMinutes}} minutes."
 },
 "header": {
"screenReaderLabel": "Poslechnout",
"myAccountLabel": "Přihlásit se",
"myAccountLogoutLabel": "Odhlásit se",
"myAccountPagesLabel": "Moje stránky",
"newToTheLibrary": "Jste v knihovně noví?",
"joinTheLibraryLabel": "Registrovat do knihovny",
"openingsLabel": "Provozní doba",
"languageLabel": "Jazyk"
 },
 "branchOpeningHours": {
"headerLabel": "Provozní doba",
"closedLabel": "Zavřeno",
"todayLabel": "Dnes",
"navigationBackLabel": "Zpět",
"navigationNextLabel": "Další",
"navigationPreviousLabel": "Předchozí",
"serviceTypeClosedLabel": "Zavřeno",
"serviceTypeStaffedLabel": "S personálem",
"serviceTypeSelfServiceLabel": "Samoobsluha",
"typeRegularLabel": "Pravidelný",
"typeSpecialLabel": "Zvláštní",
"viewAllLabel": "Zobrazit veškerou otevírací dobu"
 }
}
```

Comment: So do you want your object have a nested structure (ie representing the directory structure) or just be flat, ie all elements as toplevel with their fullpath as a key?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want it as a nested structure

Comment: Your example is not a nested structure, because all elements will be at the toplevel of the file. A nested structure would be something like `{ "modules": { "provider": { "assets": { ... }}}}` instead of `{"modules.provider.assets": {...}}`

Comment: obs, I thought that is the nested structure however no problem you know now what I am willing to have, would you please give me a solution

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of `files` to add to your JSON, and your `jsonFullPath` is created correctly the following should work

```
let files = [...]; //your json files you want to add
let myobj = files.reduce((obj, file) => {
  //not sure why you are appending an addtional "." at the end ...
  let key = path.relative(root, file).split(path.sep).join('.')
              .replace(/(_[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?)?\.json/, '') + '.' ; 
  obj[key] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8"));
  return obj;
}, {} as {[key: string]: any});
```

Ie, the callback of `Array.reduce` is executed for each file in the `files` array. It transforms the filename to your desired key, then reads the file from disk (depending on where this code is running, you probably should use the asynchronous variant of `fs.readFile()` because the `readFileSync` will block your execution) and adds the parsed object to your resulting object

If you are more comfortable with loops you can it also do this way

```
let files = [...];
let myobj : {[key: string]: any } = {};

files.forEach(file => {
  let key = path.relative(root, file).split(path.sep).join('.')
            .replace(/(_[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?)?\.json/, '') + '.' ; 
  myobj[key] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8"));
});
```

or with a simple `for .. of` loop

```
let files = [...];
let myobj : {[key: string]: any } = {};

for (let file of files) {
  let key = path.relative(root, file).split(path.sep).join('.')
            .replace(/(_[a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?)?\.json/, '') + '.' ; 
  myobj[key] = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, "utf-8"));
}
```

Comment: I got an error while I am trying your way :

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}

Comment: Sorry, missed the `typescript` tag on your question. Please see the updated answer with proper typing

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
let myJson = '{';
myJson += `${jsonFullPath}: ${rawdata}`;
myJson += '}';
```

You can just build your final string.

Comment: no that does not work

Comment: why doesn't it work?

Comment: because it doesn't create an object, and the string that is created by that code is not valid JSON, so it can't be parsed to an object ...

Comment: I've just written it in place, but the idea behind it absolutely should work `{ my.full.path.1: {original: data} }`. You do the same, just directly with object.

I was more surprised by the question itself, because the big json bloat aside, it asks about how to add custom key and a value to it, so I've just pointed to that direction.

But yeah, your full proper version is way better :).

Comment: @Gonzi Have you even tried your code? It will produce **exactly** (ie no replacements whatsoever) the follwowing *string* `"{{jsonFullPath}:{rawdata}}"`. And if you loop it, the result will be `"{{jsonFullPath}:{rawdata}}{jsonFullPath}:{rawdata}"` So how would that help a developer who is, obviously, an absolute beginner?

Comment: @derpirscher you are absolutely right, I've forgot the $ marks :(. It was the fast reply for the idea, but I can see how it wouldn't help an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

Assume that you are in a loop, map or reduce ...

So every time you pass a file (in our case the file is a JSON)

```
const file = {  "sessionTimer": {
             "accessibleTimingOut": "{{timeoutMinutes}} minutes 
              until this page times out. Move your mouse pointer 
               or press any key to extend the time with 
               {{extendMinutes}} minutes.",
                "reload": "Reload",
               "timedOut": "The page has timed out and needs to 
                be reloaded.",
                "timingOut": "seconds until this page times out 
                and needs to be 
                reloaded. Move your mouse pointer or press any 
                key to extend the time with {{extendMinutes}} 
                minutes." },
                };
var key = "filePath";
var json = {[key]:fs.readFileSync(file,"utf-8")}; 
console.log(json);
```

the console will give  :

```
{ "filePath": { "sessionTimer": {
             "accessibleTimingOut": "{{timeoutMinutes}} minutes 
              until this page times out. Move your mouse pointer 
               or press any key to extend the time with 
               {{extendMinutes}} minutes.",
                "reload": "Reload",
               "timedOut": "The page has timed out and needs to 
                be reloaded.",
                "timingOut": "seconds until this page times out 
                and needs to be 
                reloaded. Move your mouse pointer or press any 
                key to extend the time with {{extendMinutes}} 
                minutes." },
                }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that's working? Because `readFileSync` without specifying the file encoding will return a `Buffer`. And even if you specified the encoding, you add the filecontents as string ...

Comment: I agree with you, I will use it with encoding thanks, and I have another question if you might, can help as well 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566955/tool-that-extract-a-locale-from-the-path-file 

you seem very skilled developer, I am beginner in nodejs and javascript world

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).